# Stop looping audio with javascript but completing playing iteration

Tags: javascript, audio

```
<audio loop id="effect" src="/assets/web/audio/effect.mp3"></audio>

<script>document.getElementById('effect').pause();</script>
```

I stop a playing audio this way, the problem is it ends abruptly in the moment I run the javascript code. It's probably tricky but I wonder how could I stop it but allowing it to complete the playing iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('effect').loop = false;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loop

Comment: thank you, works properly in Chrome, in FF 100.0 it keeps playing for a while tho.
I guess it's poorly implemented? Anyway, I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when the system allow me.